# How to upload bulk product images?

Tags: product, image, ce-1.9.0.1, product-images

I have uploaded product through csv and upload images through FTP and allocate the path folder path into csv for images. but images not shown or allocated for product.

How could i upload bulk product images ?

Comment: Yep i also had tried the method by which you have tried to import bulk product in magento but i didn't get the perfect result. In my case i have used this process http://www.ddcantt.in/2014/12/solved-how-to-import-export-product-in.html try this hope this will fix you up and you will like this process of importing and exporting.

Answer (score 2):

The following CSV format for importing images in Magento 1.9 and above doesn't work

> sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail,
>   thumbnail_label

You must have to specify the **_media_attribute_id** and **_media_image** attribute. Without using these two attributes, you cannot import images properly. So the right CSV format for images import is as follow:

```
sku, image, image_label, small_image, small_image_label, thumbnail, thumbnail_label,_media_image,_media_attribute_id,_media_is_disabled,_media_position,_media_lable
```

[Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r_0c_P3tX48o5gsR2Lj3y_-ez02UVZS_u-8PkuhFRwc/edit?usp=sharing) to see the right csv file for Images import

*Note: Make sure the images are placed in the magento_root/media/import/ folder. Otherwise Magento could not Import the images.*

For more information, visit this [link](http://rltsquare.com/blog/?p=170)